# How to use asynchronous dask client

Tags: python-asyncio, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to undestand dask async client, and still have some questions. Here my example:

```
dask_client = await Client(
    address=settings.DASK_SCHEDULER,
    asynchronous=True
)
df_graduates = dd.read_parquet(
    '/vagrant/shared/storage/F_Graduates'
)
df_d_emp = dd.read_parquet(
    '/vagrant/shared/storage/D_Employer',
    columns=['Business_Size'])
df_graduates = df_graduates.merge(df_d_emp, on='Employer_ID', how='inner')
df_graduates = await dask_client.compute(df_graduates)
```

My questions is:

1. Should i use `await` on `dd.read_parquet`?
2. Should i use `await` on `merge`?
3. If i set wrong column name for `read_parquet` it raise excepation immediately, before `dask_client.compute`. Why it happening? If client asynchronous it should only create task, not execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The compute method isn't async friendly.  You'll have to use `await client.compute(df_graduates)` instead